# python multiprocessing cPickle.PicklingError

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Below is my parallel code using multiprocessing module's Pool. Here, parameter d is a tuple, whose word_number is an Integer and word_count is a document.

```
def perDoc(d):
    score = 0.0
    word_count = d.word_count
    word_number = d.word_number
    for i, word in enumerate(q):
        if word not in corpus_query_min:
            continue
        if word not in word_count:
            frequency = 0
        else:
            frequency = word_count.get(word)
        score += np.log(np.float(frequency + miu * corpus_word_count[i]/corpus_number)/
                    (word_number + miu))
    #loglh[d.docID] = score
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(perDoc, doc_query_list)
    pool.close()
```

I got the error like this:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.doc_'>: attribute lookup __main__.doc_ failed
```

Is this the problem of my parameter d is a tuple with document?

Comment: Your problem relates to the contents of `doc_query_list`, but you haven't provided the code that creates it. Please provide a [MCVE] if you want help.

Comment: So sorry for forgetting that part. Below, doc_tuple is a `collections.namedtuple`.

 `doc_query_list.append(doc_tuple(d.docID, doc_temp, d.word_number))`

Comment: @Yangyang.Guo. But what type of object is a `document`? Show the definition of the namedtuple and all the objects it contains.

Comment: @ekhumoro. `d.word_count` is a document. `Key` is word and `value` is  its frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psychic debugging since you gave more info (but still not a MCVE):

You created `doc_tuple`'s class with:

```
doc_tuple = collections.namedtuple('doc_', ... attributes here ...)
```

The mismatch between the string name passed (`'doc_'`), and the name it was assigned to (`doc_tuple`) causes this problem; the two names *must* match for instances of the `namedtuple` to be pickleable. Change it to:

```
# Binding matches name passed to namedtuple constructor now
doc_tuple = collections.namedtuple('doc_tuple', ... attributes here ...)
```

and make sure it's defined at the top level of the module (not inside another class or function), and it should work.

Comment: Yeah! This correctly solved my problem. But without multiprocessing, the code can run. Just a little curious.

Comment: @Yangyang.Guo: `multiprocessing` has to serialize the function, arguments, and return values of each worker task call you make, and it does so via pickling. Without `multiprocessing`, the data is never serialized, but it's still wrong to have the mismatch in binding and provided name, since it prevents all other uses of pickling as well, messes up the `repr` of the instances, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `import ipdb` in your script, remove it.